# Swift IOS exclude google app mesurment framework from pod install 'FirebaseAnalytics'

Tags: swift, google-analytics, cocoapods

i searching for a way to exclude the GoogleAppMeasurement framework in coco pods installation of FirebaseAnalytics. The GoogleAppMeasurement uses AdSupport.framework from apple, and i am restricted to use it due to political reasons. Is there a way to exclude GoogleAppMeasurement from pod installation and is the FirebaseAnalytics going to work after that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to exclude GoogleAppMeasurement. FirebaseAnalytics is mostly a wrapper around it with almost all of the FirebaseAnalytics logic provided by GoogleAppMeasurement.